# Css to create a bottom border that does not extend the length of the entire div

Tags: html, css

I have a set of containers that have a bottom border that is styled like this:

```
<div class="row col-md-4">
    <div class="my-styled-div">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row col-md-4">
    <div class="my-styled-div">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row col-md-4">
    <div class="my-styled-div">
    </div>
</div>
```

with css styling (in addition to bootstrap) like this:

```
.my-styled-div {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #848484;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #848484;
}
```

The thing I don't know how to do is prevent that bottom border from extending to the edge of the div.  What can i use to have the bottom border start, for example, `25px` in from the left side of each div?

Here is a fiddle link with a bit of a visual:
https://jsfiddle.net/jfakey/mhwb49bu/1/

Comment: you can wrap the styled div in another div that has padding in the side you want the border to not appear. [example](https://jsfiddle.net/2vns8jdz/)

Comment: @Amir -- I feel like this is 1) a hacky way to do it and 2) the padding will hide other elements i have within the div

Comment: it's a very custom request, if you look at it OOP way, you need to give a purpose to each HTML element you've got. The div with the border is not margined 25px from the right so the border should be margined. Other answers here suggest adding divs to be the borders. You can also add a specialized background. I feel those answers are basically as hacky as the one I gave you.

Comment: @AmirGeri perhaps an answer will convince me otherwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think u can style a section of a div however you certainly can use a

---

tage to get the job done

```css
 body {
    margin: 100px;
}
    .my-styled-div {
        text-align: center;
        /*padding-bottom: 10px;  remove this*/
        border-right: 1px solid #848484;
        /*border-bottom: 1px solid #848484;  also remove this */
    }

.hr-fix{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 25px;/*  << you can specify how far from the left you want the line to be */
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #848484; /* you may match this border with the right border of the <div>*/
    
}
```

```html
<div class="row col-md-4">
        <div class="my-styled-div">
            div1
            <hr class="hr-fix" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-md-4">
        <div class="my-styled-div">
            div2
             <hr class="hr-fix" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-md-4">
        <div class="my-styled-div">
            div3
            <hr class="hr-fix" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of putting the bottom border on the div, put it in a pseudo element, which you can adjust the width relative to the div. Example below uses a background-color and height of 1px on the pseudo-element to act as the bottom border.

```
.my-styled-div {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        border-right: 1px solid #848484;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
    }
    .my-styled-div::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 50%;
        height: 1px;
        background-color: #000;
    }
```

updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/to7Lgx8d/

Comment: I do like this one as well, althought it did not work in my project.  Going to keep a link to the fiddle though

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it would be to fake a border with an additional div (or you could use a pseudo selector, as @danieljkahn details below, if you don't want to alter your HTML). You could then use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to set the width of the div to 100% - 25px and then float it right:

```
.border {
    width:calc(100% - 25px);
    height:1px;
    background:#848484;
    float:right;
}
```

## [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhwb49bu/7/)

Comment: upvoting this answer because it works on the fiddle, and because vikings represent

Answer (score 0):

I think wrapping or styling another nested div is the only way to do this (unless you use a background image or a styled HR). This is because of the way CSS is designed to be used - aka the Box Model: https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

https://jsfiddle.net/mhwb49bu/12/

```
.my-styled-div {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #848484;
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.row { 
    border-right: 1px solid silver;
    border-left: 1px solid silver;
}
```